# Successful PUT request, but React, Redux app crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, put

I have a React, Redux app which should work as a CRUD application. And a part of a CRUD application is the ability to update stuff and that's what I currently have trouble with. The PUT request works (can see the changes in Robomongo), but my app crashes afterwards and the problem lies in my reducer; `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'item' of undefined` (yeah, `item` is not the best naming, sorry).

I'd like to walk you through the process of the PUT request, because `code > text` after all.

I will start where my action is created, because I guess you can figure out I have a form as my legit starting point.

So, here's my action (sorry for the wall of code)

#### Action:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../../../../settings'
import { merge } from 'lodash'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export function updateSettings(id, updatedValues, controller, door) {
  const custom_name = updatedValues.custom_name
  const location = updatedValues.location
  const open_duration = updatedValues.open_duration
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    const door = state.fetchDoors.doors.find(val => val._id === id.itemId)
    const controller = state.fetchDoors.controllers.find(
      controller => controller._id === door.controller
    )
    console.log('door', door) // Returns updated object
    console.log('controller', controller) // Returns updated object

    const doorPayload = {
      ...door,
      custom_name,
      location
    }

    const controllerPayload = {
      ...controller,
      open_duration
    }

    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id.itemId}`, doorPayload)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DOOR_UPDATING' })
        dispatch({
          type: 'DOOR_UPDATED_SUCCESS',
          doorPayload
        })
      })

    axios
      .put(
        `${settings.hostname}/controllers/${door.controller}`,
        controllerPayload
      )
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CONTROLLER_UPDATING' })
        dispatch({
          type: 'CONTROLLER_UPDATING_SUCCESS',
          controllerPayload
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

And here's my reducer

#### Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false
}

export const settings = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DOOR_UPDATING':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'DOOR_UPDATED_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, item: action.payload.item, isLoading: false } // Here's where the error occurs

    case 'CONTROLLER_UPDATING':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true }

    case 'CONTROLLER_UPDATING_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, item: action.payload.item, isLoading: false }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

So the error occur inside of my reducer (I've added a comment) and I really don't understand why, now when the PUT request changes the data inside of my database. I assume there's something silly I'm missing, but I can't fix it. All help is really appreciated and if more code/ info needed just let me know.

Thanks for reading.

#### Edit:

Here's how my `door` object looks like:
[image]

Comment: Two questions: 1. what is the shape of `door`?  2. is `state.fetchDoors` an `object`? (i wonder why it called `fetch...`)

Comment: @Sag1v What do you mean with "shape"? Yes `state.fetchDoors` is an object. I am getting it from my redux store.

Comment: shape as in what are the properties this object has? for example: `{a:'foo',b:'bar'}`

Comment: @Sag1v Oh, I understand. I hope it was okay to post a screenshot of that it looks like. Please see my edit. Thanks for taking your time by the way.

Comment: well i don't see any `item` property in there...

Comment: @Sag1v What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your reducer you are expecting and `action` with the shape of:
`{type: 'something', payload: 'something else'}`
But when you dispatch the action you don't have a property of `payload`.
this is what you are dispatching:

```
{
  ...door, // this will spread all properties of door (which doesn't have a property with the name payload)
  custom_name,
  location
}
```

Then you are trying to access `action.payload.item` hence you get the error:

> Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

`payload` is never defined in your `action` (by the way nor `item` was).

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct. Oh man I feel silly now. I updated my code and renamed it to: `item: action.doorPayload` and `item: action.controllerPayload`. Thank you so much.